# 18.04: Connect a Brother DCP-1610 through an Orange Livebox?

Tags: networking, printing, brother

I have a dual boot system which allows me to use Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu 18.04. My [Brother DCP-1610](https://support.brother.com/g/b/spec.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1610w_eu_as) can be accessed from my wife's computer through the [Orange Livebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Livebox) using Windows 7.

I can run the printer when it is attached directly to my PC, using either Windows or Ubuntu,  but I have not found a route to connect it to my computer using the Livebox whether under Windows 7 or under Ubuntu.

I am not bothered by the lack of access under Windows but I have a strong need to be able to use the printer from Ubuntu via the Livebox. How should I set up the connection in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider bypassing the Orange Livebox and printing directly to the WiFi transceiver of that Brother printer? If you, you may [download the .DEB driver file](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1610w_eu_as&os=128) from Brother, and [install it](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1610w_eu_as&faqid=faq00100678_000).

If your OS does not have a 32 bit library as standard, install *ia32-libs* or *lib32z1*

Install the LPD/LPRng driver and the CUPS driver using the *--force-architecture* option.

If the /usr/lib64 directory exists, check whether the "br (printer name) filter" file exists under /usr/lib64/cups/filter. If not, copy it from the /usr/lib/cups/filter directory.

Set up the printer using "http://localhost:631/printers".

=

Alternatively, if you use a desktop sans WiFi and she uses a Windows laptop, you could reconfigure her PC to print to the WiFi from Windows 7, and connect directly to the Brother from your PC, instead.

Comment: I have tried out your suggestions. I prowled around inside the Terminal without finding the files you suggested. Eventually I though "to hell with this!" and tried a Ping. That seemed to succeed so I tried to print. That succeeded too, I have no idea why. Many thanks all the same.